# creating a new array out of an object

Tags: javascript, object, for-in-loop

I've created a JavaScript object to get the number of times a character repeats in a string:

```
function getFrequency(string) {
  //  var newValsArray =[];
    var freq = {};
    for (var i=0; i<string.length;i++) {
        var character = string.charAt(i);
        if (freq[character]) {
           freq[character]++;
        } else {
           freq[character] = 1;
        }
    }

    return freq;
}
```

Now, I'm trying to construct a new string composed of the keys & their properties (the letters) & numbers of times the letters repeat if the number (property) is more than one but I keep getting undefined and I don't know why:

```
function newString(freq){
  var newValsArray = [];
  for (var prop in freq) {
    if (freq[prop]>1){
      newValsArray.push(prop + freq[prop]);
    }
    else if (freq[prop] < 2){
      newValsArray.push(prop);
    }
  }
  return newValsArray;
}
```

I feel like my syntax is off or something... if anyone has any suggestions, I'd really appreciate it...

Comment: `newString` does not return anything...

Answer (score 0):

You aren't explicitly returning anything from `newString()`, so it will return `undefined`. It sounds like you want something like this:

```
return newValsArray.join('');
```

at the end of `newString()` to construct an actual string (instead of returning an array). With that change, `newString(getFrequency("Hello there")` will return `'He3l2o thr'`.

Comment: thank u - I just edited it- I didn't catch that at first but then I did but it's still not rlly working for me unfortunately.... thanks though @Ted Hopp- I made it sort of work but it's still not perfect

Comment: @H.Hirschfeld - Can you provide details on what's still wrong?

Comment: I want to be able to return the value of newValsArray in a single function @Ted Hopp i.e. newString(getFrequency(string))... I think I should of just called getFrequency on string w/in newString()- I just didn't form it right- I was taking a test & just had so much test anxiety/couldn't think straight & didn't structure this function as well as I could of :-( thanks 4 your help

Comment: @H.Hirschfeld - Well, my sympathies for the test stress. For future reference, you can turn an array of characters (or anything, actually) into a single string object by joining all the elements as I showed in my answer. (You can optionally add a separator between elements, but using the empty string like I showed will cause all the elements to be strung together without delimiters, which is what I thought you wanted.)

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function getFrequency(string) {
   //  var newValsArray =[];
   var freq = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
     var character = string.charAt(i);
     if (freq[character]) {
       freq[character] ++;
     } else {
       freq[character] = 1;
     }
   }

   return freq;
 }

 function newString(freq) {
   var newValsArray = [];
   for (var prop in freq) {
     if (freq[prop] > 1) {
       newValsArray.push(prop + freq[prop]);
     } else if (freq[prop] < 2) {
       newValsArray.push(prop);
     }
   }
   return newValsArray.join("");
 }

 var mystring = "Here are some letters to see if we have any freq matches and so on.";
 var results = newString(getFrequency(mystring));
 var elem = document.getElementById("results");
 elem.innerHTML = results;
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from the `newString` function. Add `return newString;` as the last line of the `newString` function. Adding that line does result in something being returned, though I can't tell if it is what you expected.

```js
var text = "asdfjhwqe  fj asdj qwe hlsad f jasdfj asdf alhwe sajfdhsadfjhwejr";
var myFreq = getFrequency(text);
show(myFreq);
var myNewValsArray = newString(myFreq);
show(myNewValsArray);

function getFrequency(string) {
  //  var newValsArray =[];
    var freq = {};
    for (var i=0; i<string.length;i++) {
        var character = string.charAt(i);
        if (freq[character]) {
           freq[character]++;
        } else {
           freq[character] = 1;
        }
    }

    return freq;
}

function newString(freq){
  var newValsArray = [];
  for (var prop in freq) {
    if (freq[prop]>1){
      newValsArray.push(prop + freq[prop]);
    }
    else if (freq[prop] < 2){
      newValsArray.push(prop);
    }
  }
  return newValsArray; // ******** ADD THIS LINE
}

function show(msg) {
  document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(msg, null, 2) + "</pre>");
}
```

Comment: thanks- I just edited it @Andrew Willems - I just didn't get that part pasted in there... I wish I could do all of this in one function... ahhhh ;-) I'm so stressed out rn over this- thank u 4 your help

Comment: So what _do_ you want it to return?

Comment: it's ok, i was taking a test- I wanted it to all work as One function instead of having to do 2 function calls @Andrew Willems- i hate programming tests- i so don't do my best work... don't be upset if i erase this question either- i get so nervous my teacher will see ;-)